# Is the mapping achieved by the discrete Frechet Distance the best achievable pair decomposition?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, metric-spaces

I have the following proble:
There are 2 sequences $P$ and $Q$ composed by $M$ and $N$ points respectively.
I want to calculate the discrete Frechet distance between them.

This operation outputs also a set $R = [(A_0,B_0),(A_1,B_1),\ldots,(A_k,B_k)]$ representing the mappings between the points of sequence $P$ and $R$, where $A_i$ 
and $B_i$ contain points coming from $P$ and $Q$ respectively.

Now: the sequence $R$ achieved when calculating the Frechet distance is the one that minimizes the diameter of each subset $(A_i,B_i)$ ?